# multiple plot arrangement by level of one variable in base plot in r

Tags: r, graphics, plot, radix, par

Here is my data and plot

```
nmar <- seq (1, 100, 5)
position= rep(nmar, 5)
n = length (nmar )
chr = rep(1:5, each = n )

mapdata <- data.frame (chr, position, 
 snpname = paste("SNP-", 1:length (position), sep = ""))
mapdata


chr.lab = 1 ; mbar.col = "blue"
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2),nc=1)) # works for two but I need to extend it to 
       n (which is level of chr = 5)

# plot level 1
mapdata1 <- mapdata[mapdata$chr == 1,]
m <- par()$mar
m[1] <- m[3] <- 0
par(mar=m)
# Set the limits of the  plot
plot(mapdata1$position,mapdata1$position-mapdata1$position, type="n",
   axes=FALSE, 
xlab="", ylab="Chromsome", yaxt="n" )

polygon(
  c(0,max(mapdata1$position + 0.08 * max(mapdata1$position)),max(mapdata1$position)+
     0.08 * max(mapdata1$position),0),
  .2*c(-0.3,-0.3,0.3,0.3),
  col= mbar.col
)
segments(mapdata1$position, -.3, mapdata1$position, .3 )
text(mapdata1$position, -.7, mapdata1$snpname, srt = 90, cex.lab = chr.lab)
text(mapdata1$position,  .7, mapdata1$position,cex.lab = chr.lab )
text(0, labels = c("Chr 2"))
```

Second level

```
# plot level 2
mapdata2 <- mapdata[mapdata$chr == 2,]
m <- par()$mar
m[1] <- m[3] <- 0
par(mar=m)
# Set the limits of the  plot
plot(mapdata2$position,mapdata2$position-mapdata1$position, type="n", axes=FALSE, 
xlab="", ylab="Chromsome", yaxt="n" )

polygon(
  c(0,max(mapdata2$position + 0.08 * max(mapdata2$position)),max(mapdata2$position)+  
 0.08 * max(mapdata2$position),0),
  .2*c(-0.3,-0.3,0.3,0.3),
  col= mbar.col
)
segments(mapdata2$position, -.3, mapdata2$position, .3 )
text(mapdata2$position, -.7, mapdata2$snpname, srt = 90, cex.lab = chr.lab)
text(mapdata2$position,  .7, mapdata2$position,cex.lab = chr.lab )
text(0, labels = c("Chr 2"))
```

Output
[image]

(1) How can I automate the process for n levels - extending similar plot to n levels of chr 
(2) If you see the barsize with same specification has changed, may be due to different plot area. How can I adjust it so make all plots identical?

Comment: Any particular reason for wanting to stick to base plots? ggplot2 and lattice provide easy solution for creating these kinds of composite plots see these links for a lot of examples http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/06/28/ggplot2-version-of-figures-in-lattice-multivariate-data-visualization-with-r-part-1/ http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/06/29/ggplot2-version-of-figures-in-lattice-multivariate-data-visualization-with-r-part-2/ http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/ggplot2-version-of-figures-in-lattice-multivariate-data-visualization-with-r-part-3/

Comment: I agree that ggplot2 and lattice are better, however I feel they are difficult to manipulate, are not they ?

Comment: I find ggplot2 quite easy to use once you get the hang of it. Imo it is defintely worth it to switch to ggplot2, or lattice for that matter, although after working with both of them I prefer ggplot2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot` is definitely the way to go here. But if you really want to stick with base `plot`, then this function would work:

```
plot.as.stack= function(mapdata1, mbar.col = "blue"){
    # mapdata1 <- mapdata[mapdata$chr == chr,]
    m <- par()$mar
    m[1] <- m[3] <- 0
    par(mar=m)
    # Set the limits of the  plot
    plot(mapdata1$position,mapdata1$position-mapdata1$position, type="n",
       axes=FALSE, 
    xlab="", ylab="Chromsome", yaxt="n" )

    polygon(
      c(0,max(mapdata1$position + 0.08 * max(mapdata1$position)),max(mapdata1$position)+
         0.08 * max(mapdata1$position),0),
      .2*c(-0.3,-0.3,0.3,0.3),
      col= mbar.col
    )
    segments(mapdata1$position, -.3, mapdata1$position, .3 )
    text(mapdata1$position, -.7, mapdata1$snpname, srt = 90, cex.lab = chr.lab)
    text(mapdata1$position,  .7, mapdata1$position,cex.lab = chr.lab )
    text(0, labels = paste("Chr",unique(mapdata1$chr)))
}

# Example Run.
par(mfrow=c(length(unique(mapdata$chr)),1))
x=by(mapdata,factor(mapdata$chr),plot.as.stack) # Assigned to x to prevent output
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

As you can see, I just took your code, put it into a function, and then ran `by` on it. Note that this would run the function on *all* of the levels of `chr`. You could modify it so that the function takes the value of chr instead:

```
plot.as.stack = function(chr){
    mapdata1 <- mapdata[mapdata$chr == chr,]
    ...
}
```

And then run the function with values of chr:

```
par(mfrow=c(5,1))
sapply(1:5,plot.as.stack)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```